# Trying to get 0 as minimum value vertical axis in chart of SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on a SSRS report which requires a chart to show vertical axis in 'M' or 'K' like 0, 2M, 4M. I got a custom formatting formula which adds an 'M' or 'K' with numbers -

```
=Switch(Fields!TotalSpendCurrent.Value < 1000, "0.#", Fields!TotalSpendCurrent.Value < 1000000, "#,.#K", true, "#,,M")
```

But with this I am getting 'M' or 'K' as minimum value not 0.

[image]

**Current Output Screen**

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some data! Or you can use Format function to apply on condition base!

Comment: You can assume any data which is more than 1000000 and I need to represent it on chart's vertical axis starting as 0, 2M, 4M. For example - you have Total Spend with maximum value of 16000000 and Month for X axis from June to Dec.

Comment: So if `Fields!TotalSpendCurrent.Value` is less than 1000 then you want to show `0` right? not `M`

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to get.

Comment: Seems you are very new to SSRS, can you please provide current actual output screen!

Comment: Added screen shot of the chart, hope this will help.

Comment: please check my below answer and update me!

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
=Switch(CInt(Fields!TotalSpendCurrent.Value) < 1000, Format(Fields!TotalSpendCurrent.Value,"0.#"), 
CInt(Fields!TotalSpendCurrent.Value) < 1000000, Format(Fields!TotalSpendCurrent.Value,"#,.#K"), 
true, Format(Fields!TotalSpendCurrent.Value,"#,,M"))
```

*Let me if it works or not!*

Comment: No, now it showing only one number with M or K in all scales - 1M, 1M, 1M

Comment: see it will show you the whatever the values we have set to `Fields!TotalSpendCurrent.Value` - so please check all the values or if possible please show here

Comment: Values are correct as they are starting from 0 to Mills but, this isn't working.